# R for loop through vectors, if subscript out of bounds change to certain value

Tags: r, for-loop, integer

I have a vector list where sometimes the values range 1 to 7 and sometimes 1 to 5. I want to loop through them and get frequency count using the function `table` and then place those values into a data frame, but I receive a `subscript out of bounds` error. It does this because it expects an `integer` value. When this happens, I would like to set the integer value to 0.

Is there an easy function I could wrap around the `integer`value, e.g. `somefunction(t[[6]])` that returns `0`?

```
#list of vectors, the first has values 1 to 7, the second has 1 to 5, 
#the third is 1 to 7 again and is only included to show that my real problem has many
# more vectors to evaluate


vectors<-list(c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7),
c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5),
c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7))

#empty data frame
df<-data.frame()
#loop through list of vectors and get frequncy count per list
for (i in 1:length(vectors)) {
  #count frquency of each value as variable t
  t<-table(vectors[[i]])
      #put frequency count of each value in the data frame - the problem is 
      #that in the second vector, there are only values of 1 to 5, so t[[6]] 
      #reports "subscript out of bounds". I want to change this to a value of 0
  df<-rbind(df,cbind(t[[1]],t[[2]],t[[3]],t[[4]],t[[5]],t[[6]],t[[7]]))
}

df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping, we can convert the `list` to a two column `data.frame` with `stack` after setting the names of the `list` and then apply `table`

```
table(stack(setNames(vectors, seq_along(vectors)))[2:1])
#  values
#ind  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
#  1  2  2  3  2  3  4  5
#  2  2  2  3  2 12  0  0
#  3  2  2  3  2  3  4  5
```

The above would be a `table` object.  If we need to convert to `data.frame` (without reshaping to 'long' format)

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(stack(setNames(vectors, seq_along(vectors)))[2:1]))
```

Here, we apply the `table` only once and it would be more efficient and less complicated because it automatically finds the unique values.  If we are looping, then we have to find the unique values beforehand to add missing levels to be counted as 0

---

With a loop, we can convert the individual `list` elements to `factor` with `levels` specified as the `unique` of all the elements

```
un1 <- sort(unique(unlist(vectors)))
t(sapply(vectors, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = un1))))
```

---

In the `for` loop, we could use `rbind`, but with `rbind` it would expect the column names to be same or the lengths to be same.  So, instead of `rbind`, an option is `bind_rows` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame()
for(i in seq_along(vectors)) {
      tbl1 <- table(vectors[[i]])
      df <- bind_rows(df, tbl1)
 }
```

By default, `bind_rows` fills with `NA` for columns that are not found.  Then we replace the `NA` to 0

```
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
```

But, this is not an efficient option as the one showed with calling `table` once